# Error in generating checksumhash(Paytm Gateway) on Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate PayTm gateway from Djnago as backend but my program is encountering error while generating checksumhash.
Below are my code Snippet:

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
class TrxnDetail(models.Model):
    MID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ORDER_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CUST_ID = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    TXN_AMOUNT = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    CHANNEL_ID = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    WEBSITE = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    MOBILE_NO = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    EMAIL = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ORDER_ID
```

### views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from gateway.models import TrxnDetail
from gateway.serializers import TrxnSerializer
from gateway.Checksum import generate_checksum
from django.conf import settings


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = TrxnDetail.objects.all()
        serializer = TrxnSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TrxnSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            sdata=serializer.data

            mid,order_id,cust_id,
            txn_amount,channel_id,
            website,industry_type_id,
            mobile_no,email=sdata.get('MID'),sdata.get('ORDER_ID'),
            sdata.get('CUST_ID'),sdata.get('TXN_AMOUNT'),
            sdata.get('CHANNEL_ID'),sdata.get('WEBSITE'),
            sdata.get('INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID'),sdata.get('MOBILE_NO'),
            sdata.get('EMAIL'),
            param_dict = dict()
            param_dict['MID']=mid
            param_dict['ORDER_ID']=order_id
            param_dict['CUST_ID']=cust_id
            param_dict['TXN_AMOUNT']=txn_amount
            param_dict['CHANNEL_ID']=channel_id
            param_dict['WEBSITE']=website
            param_dict['INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID']=industry_type_id
            param_dict['MOBILE_NO']=mobile_no
            param_dict['EMAIL']=email
            print(generate_checksum(param_dict,settings.PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY))
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Im using ModelSerializer and [CheckSum.py](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_App_Checksum_Kit_Python/blob/master/Python%20v3.x/Checksum.py)

I am getting following error:[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhYrD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3, make sure you have installed pycryptodome first. The AES.new() function of encode and decode functions in your Checksum file needs utf-8 encoded parameters.

Replace the functions with the below code:

```
def __encode__(to_encode, iv, key):
    # Pad
    to_encode = __pad__(to_encode)
    # Encrypt
    c = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CBC, iv.encode('utf-8'))
    to_encode = c.encrypt(to_encode.encode('utf-8'))
    # Encode
    to_encode = base64.b64encode(to_encode)
    return to_encode


def __decode__(to_decode, iv, key):
    # Decode
    to_decode = base64.b64decode(to_decode)
    # Decrypt
    c = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CBC, iv.encode('utf-8'))
    to_decode = c.decrypt(to_decode)
    # remove pad
    return __unpad__(to_decode)
```

I hope that helps.